# Chosen dropdown with angular required validation

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I am using `angular js` and the `chosen` plugin for my dropdowns. I want a validator to show when nothing has been selected in the dropdown. But because `chosen` replaces the `select` with some `divs` and `uls`, and the `select` gets hidden, the validation doesn't work. Is there a way I could achieve this with `angular`? This is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate name="newEmployeeForm">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label for="username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User</label>
           <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" name="user" data-placeholder="Choose a user" ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="u.fullName for u in users" list="users" chosen required></select>
               </div>
               <span class="error" data-ng-show="newEmployeeForm.user.$error.required">*</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="employee.email" required>
            </div>
            <span class="error" data-ng-show="newEmployeeForm.email.$error.required">*</span>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" data-ng-disabled="newEmployeeForm.$invalid">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

the directive:

```
app.directive('chosen', function () {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                list: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                scope.$watch('list', function (newVaue, oldValue) {
                    if (newVaue == oldValue) {
                        return;
                    }
                    element.chosen();
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Save Changes button is disabled because there is no value in select, if there is no value in select what so you want to do

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan of course that is why it is disabled, that is the wanted functionality. But I want the "*" to be displayed when nothing is selected in the dropdown. And that doesn't happen. It doesn't happen because the "chosen" hides the select and draws the data in the form of an "ul". So that has to be validated, but I can't figure out how. It only works on the input.

Comment: even nothing is selected "*" is there check this out http://jsfiddle.net/AAJZg/12/

Comment: have you missed anything....

Comment: that works because chosen is not loaded. that is a regular select that you have there. I have edited my post with the directive for loading chosen, but the chosen.jquery.js file still has to be added.

Comment: @jmelosegui yeah, I have stopped using chosen, at the moment using ui-select, pretty happy with it: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select